# How to merge files based on key value pairs and also sort it using Java?

Tags: java, file, sorting, external-sorting

I have written a program similar to external sort. I got a good idea from [this blog](http://exceptional-code.blogspot.com/2011/07/external-sorting-for-sorting-large.html). Here, they are trying to do external sort of only numbers. My requirement is little different. 
My input file can have over million records and it is difficult to sort them in-memory, so I have to make use of my disk. I divide my input into various slices, sort it and then store it in temporary files. And then merge sorted output into a single file. Below I am able to split it into temporary files and then merge only the keys.

I have an input file as below:

```
key1 abc
key2 world
key1 hello
key3 tom
key7 yankie
key3 apple
key5 action
key7 jack
key4 apple
key2 xon
key1 lemon
```

Let's say the size of the file on disk is 10 and maximum items memory buffer can hold is 4, so what I have done is taken 4 records at a time and stored it in HashMap, sorted my values along with the updated count. This input will be split into 3 sorted files as shown below. You can see, for each key I have a count and also the lexicographically highest value.

temp-file-0.txt

```
key1: 2, hello
key2: 1, world
key3: 1, tom
```

temp-file-1.txt

```
key5: 1, action
key3: 1, apple
key7: 2, yankie
```

temp-file-2.txt

```
key1: 1, lemon
key2: 1, xon
key4: 1, apple
```

then after merging all these 3 files, output should look like this:

```
key1: 3 lemon
key2: 2 xon
key3: 2 world
key5: 1 action
key7: 2 yankie
```

I am not sure about the logic of merging the entire line along with count and the lexicographically highest value for that key, my below code is able to give me all keys, something like this:

```
key1
key1
key2
key2
key3
key4
key5
key3
key7
```

In below code, I am opening each file and merging them, then writing back to disk into a new single file called `external-sorted.txt`

```
    static int N = 10; // size of the file in disk
     static int M = 4; // max items the memory buffer can hold
     int slices = (int) Math.ceil((double) N/M);
     String tfile = "temp-file-";

//Reading all the 3 temp files
     BufferedReader[] brs = new BufferedReader[slices];
     String[] topNums = new String[slices];
     for(i = 0; i<slices; i++){
      brs[i] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tfile + Integer.toString(i) + ".txt"));
      String t = brs[i].readLine();
      String[] kv = t.split(":");

      if(t!=null){
        topNums[i] = kv[0];
      }
    //topNums [key1, key5, key1]
     }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("external-sorted.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){

    String min = topNums[0];
    System.out.println("min:"+min);
    int minFile = 0;

    for(j=0; j<slices; j++){

    if(min.compareTo(topNums[j])>0)
      {
      min = topNums[j];
      minFile = j;
      }
    }

     pw.println(min);
      String t = brs[minFile].readLine();
     String[] kv = new String[2];
      if (t != null)
         kv = t.split(":");
         topNums[minFile] = kv[0];

    }

       for (i = 0; i < slices; i++)
        brs[i].close();

       pw.close();
       fw.close();
      }
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Please ask, if you have any questions. TIA.

Comment: _"I need help merging..."_ unless you can explain what is not working about what you've done, and ask a ***specific*** question, the post is off-topic.  As it stands you are effectively asking for someone to read all your code and then figure out the part you don't know how to do.  Please re-visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I am editing my question. Apologies if it was taken negatively.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Can you please remove your downvote, I have updated my question with clear explanation?

Comment: Please add comments for downvote, if there is anything illogical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, something like this works, I'm sure there are better ways, but at the moment I'm not up to thinking really:

```
    // Declare Scanner Object to read our file
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(stringRepresentingLocationOfYourFileHere));

    // create Map that will contain keys in sorted order (TreeMap)
    // along with last value assigned to the key
    Map<String, String> mapa = new TreeMap<>();

    // another map to hold keys from first map and number of
    // occurrences of those keys (repetitions), this could have been
    // done using single Map as well, but whatever
    Map<String, Integer> mapaDva = new HashMap<>();

    // String array that will hold words of each line of our .txt file
    String[] line;

    // we loop until we reach end of our .txt file
    while(in.hasNextLine()){

        // check if map already contains given key, if it does
        // increment value by 1 otherwise initialize the value with 1
        if (mapa.put((line = in.nextLine().split(" "))[0], line[1]) != null)
            mapaDva.put(line[0], mapaDva.get(line[0])+1);
        else
            mapaDva.put(line[0], 1);
    }

    // loop through our maps and print out keys, number of 
    //repetitions, last assigned value
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> m : mapa.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + mapaDva.get(m.getKey()) + " " + m.getValue());
    }
```

If there is something specific that is unclear about this code, please ask.

**Sample input file:**

```
key1 abcd
key2 zzz
key1 tommy
key3 world
```

**Output when done:**

```
key1 2 tommy
key2 1 zzz
key3 1 world
```

EDIT 2 (solution for when dealing with multiple files):

```
 // array of File objects that hold path to all your files to iterate through
    File[] files = {new File("file1.txt"),
                    new File("file2.txt"),
                    new File("file3.txt")};

    Scanner in;
    Map<String, String> mapa = new TreeMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> mapaDva = new HashMap<>();
    String[] line;

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // assign new File to Scanner on each iteration (go through our File array)
        in = new Scanner(files[i]);
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            if (mapa.put((line = in.nextLine().split(" "))[0], line[1]) != null)
                mapaDva.put(line[0], mapaDva.get(line[0])+1);
            else
                mapaDva.put(line[0], 1);
        }
    }



    for (Map.Entry<String, String> m : mapa.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + mapaDva.get(m.getKey()) + " " + m.getValue());
    }
```

So we store all the File objects in our File array and we go through each and every one of them, combine all the content and print out final result:

**3 sample input files:**

**file1.txt**

```
key1 abcd
key2 zzz
key1 tommy
key3 world
```

**file2.txt**

```
key1 abc
key3 xxx
key1 tommy
key6 denver
```

**file3.txt**

```
key5 lol
key8 head
key6 tommy
key6 denver
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
key1 4 tommy
key2 1 zzz
key3 2 xxx
key5 1 lol
key6 3 denver
key8 1 head
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, but I am trying to merge the different files, that are already sorted. I have edited my question. Thx

Comment: Repeat reading file lines for each of the files, you could make use of a loop, store your file paths into a String array and loop through array and apply this code to each file. You'll get what you want in the end.

Comment: Try to think about it, if you still can't figure it out, just let me know I'll edit my answer and explain how to do it.

Comment: ` if (mapa.put((line = brs[i].readLine().split(":"))[0], line[1]) != null)` , gives null pointer exception, if you read my question, now my files are of form `key1: 2, hello` from temp0.txt, and I need to merge it with `key1: 1, lemon` from temp2.txt.

Comment: @Techiee I've appended answer for multi-files.

Comment: I see, you are not sorting files and then storing, you simply split the files and then sorting all of them at once. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162233/discussion-between-techiee-and-gcp).